# How many configurations

Tags: permutations

If I have twelve objects, each of which can be in one of three states (say on, off, on/off), how many ways can the group of twelve be configured -- by changing the state of each object?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please state what you have done so far. Specifically, have you tried to solve a simpler version, e.g. with just two or three objects?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities for each object. so you have $3^{12}$ possibilities